# Is there anyway for switch case statement to do count only the value less than assigned?

Tags: java

Sorry if the title is misleading, but I don't know how to put my question in words. Take a look at the code below. When i run it, if i enter any value between 100 and 109, it will show me "HD-10", but i only want mark == 100 to get HD-10, and anything above 100 will show invalid. Any tips?

ps I did import scanner from java.util, just don't know why it's not showing up in the code below.

thanks in advance for the help!

```
public class GradeCase_testResults
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        float total;
        int mark;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter the student's mark");
        total = sc.nextInt ();

        mark = (int)total / 10;

        switch(mark)
        {
            case 1: case 2:case 3:case 4:
                System.out.println("F-" + mark);
                break;
            case 5:
                System.out.println("P-5");
                break;
            case 6:
                System.out.println("C-6");
                break;
            case 7:
                System.out.println("D-7");
                break;
            case 8:
                System.out.println("HD-8");
                break;
            case 9:
                System.out.println("HD-9");
                break;
            case 10: 
                System.out.println("HD-10");
                break;
            default:
                System.out.println("Invalid");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem is not your switch, but `total / 10`. Because (int) 109 / 10 = 10

Comment: If your input will always be `100` or greater, consider just subtracting `100` instead of doing division, it avoids any potential mess arising from rounding errors

Comment: What if someone enters 99, what should it display?

Comment: @PetterFriberg if they entered 99, it should return "HD-9"

Comment: so 109 should not return 10 but 99 should return 9, your are best of with an if on top, if totale >100 ... mark=11 else...

Answer (score 1):

You have your validation in wrong place. You should ensure input to be in [0,100] range.

EDIT:
The problem is that you try to interpret wrong input.
In your case, I guess the only valid input is in range [0,100] as it makes no sense to score more than 100 points or any negative value.
Ensure proper input and your problem will go away :)
You can do something like this:

```
do
{
    System.out.println("Please enter the student's mark");
    total = sc.nextInt ();
} while(total < 0 || total > 100)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `(int) 10x / 10` will always return 10 for values of X between 0 and 9. Therefore it hits the case where `mark` is 10.

Similar for the others when you input for example 98, it'll fall into case 9.

Unfortunately, unlike kotlin, in Java switches need constant expressions and greater than is not constant evaluating to a value.

Either switch to if statements or go with the values that you input and don't do the division you are doing as input to the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mark = Math.floorDiv(int, int);` instead which will round it down for you correctly.

So change

```
mark = (int)total / 10;
```

to:

```
mark = Math.floorDiv(total, 10);
```

And change your `float total` to `int total`, I do not really know why you had it as `float` before and cast it to `int`.

[Math.floorDiv(int, int) docs found here.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floorDiv-int-int-)

**EDIT:**

Since you want to use a *float* so decimal points are accounted for you also need to change the `Scanner` to use `nextFloat()`:

```
System.out.println("Please enter the student's mark");
float total = sc.nextFloat();
mark = Math.floorDiv((int) total, 10);
```

Then you can cast to `int` just as before, and `floorDiv` will still operate correctly.

Comment: the reason is i wanted to enter the mark as a float, lets say 94.5, and it should give me back 9 since int of 94.5/10 = 9

Comment: @James Wong Then you are already doing it wrong, because you are using `sc.nextInt` and if you type `94.5` into it you will get an exception.  If you are using `nextInt` there is no reason to use a float with it.  Use `.nextFloat()` then, change it back to a `float`, and cast it to an int like you were doing and my code should still work.

Comment: @James Wong I added an EDIT to show you how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your "/" to "%" (modulo):

```
mark = (int)total % 10;
```

and the:

```
case 10: 
System.out.println("HD-10");
```

to:

```
case 0: 
System.out.println("HD-10");
```

and seems it is working, like you want.

Comment: This does not work correctly for other cases, if you type `75` it will return the case for `5`, not for `7`.

Answer (score 0):

Validate input first. Use only switch if valid. Pseudo code:

```
if(total>=0 && total <=100)
    switch...
else
    System.out.println("Invalid");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am going to approach this from readability standpoint.

Although it may seem cute to convert the values from `float total` (0-100) to `int mark` (1-10) (hey, what happened to zero?) and use a switch statement to then finally return the mapped String, but it is entirely confusing to read and prone to bugs.

Why not just use some old-fashioned comparisons?

```java
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the student's mark");
    System.out.println(getMark(sc.nextFloat()));
  }

  private static String getMark(float total) {
    if (total < 50) return "F-";
    if (total < 60) return "P-5";
    if (total < 70) return "C-6";
    if (total < 80) return "D-7";
    if (total < 90) return "HD-8";
    if (total < 100) return "HD-9";
    return "HD-10";
  }
```